# How do I build Boost.Log exported with bcp?

Tags: boost

I'd like to use Boost.Log for my project, but I don't want to include the whole Boost library in my code repository. So I use `bcp` to copy just what I think is necessary to build Boost.Log from the Boost distribution in `../boost_1_67_0`:

```
cd boost
bcp --boost=../boost_1_67_0/ log build config .
```

Then I run:

```
./bootstrap.sh
./b2
```

But this fails with the following messages:

```
predef.jam: No such file or directory
.../boost/tools/build/src/kernel/modules.jam:314: in modules.import
IMPORT error: rule "check" unknown in module "predef".
.../boost/tools/build/src/build/project.jam:1069: in import
libs/test/build/Jamfile.v2:9: in modules.load
.../boost/tools/build/src/build/project.jam:325: in load-jamfile
.../boost/tools/build/src/build/project.jam:64: in load
.../boost/tools/build/src/build/project.jam:89: in load-used-projects
.../boost/tools/build/src/build/project.jam:75: in load
.../boost/tools/build/src/build/project.jam:145: in project.find
.../boost/tools/build/src/build-system.jam:618: in load
.../boost/tools/build/src/kernel/modules.jam:295: in import
.../boost/tools/build/src/kernel/bootstrap.jam:139: in boost-build
.../boost/boost-build.jam:17: in module scope
```

I'm running this on macOS.

Answer (score 1):

Building Boost.Log requires also the Predef library:

```
cd boost
bcp --boost=../boost_1_67_0/ log build config predef .
```

Then run `bootstrap.sh` and `b2` normally.